# Not sure where to use an await operator in an async method

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

After reading lot of stuff about async/await, I still not sure where do I use await operator in my async method:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> DailySchedule(int professionalId, DateTime date)
    {
        var professional = professionalServices.Find(professionalId);            
        var appointments = scheduleService.SearchForAppointments(date, professional);
        appointments = scheduleService.SomeCalculation(appointments);

        return PartialView(appointments);
    }
```

Should I create an async version for all 3 method and call like this?

```
        var professional = await professionalServices.FindAsync(professionalId);            
        var appointments = await scheduleService.SearchForAppointmentsAsync(date, professional);
        appointments = await scheduleService.SomeCalculationAsync(appointments);
```

or Should I make async only the first one ?

```
        var professional = await professionalServices.FindAsync(professionalId);            
        var appointments = scheduleService.SearchForAppointments(date, professional);
        appointments = scheduleService.SomeCalculation(appointments);
```

What´s is the difference?

Comment: Can any of those operations take more than, say 30 milliseconds?

Comment: Yes, only the SearchForAppointmnents in this case.

Comment: Remember, marking something as `async` does not *make* it async. It has to already be asynchronous. Is it *possible* for you to write an asynchronous version of SearchForAppointments, call it SearchForAppointmentsAsync, that runs asynchronously? (Not necessarily on another thread; maybe it is asynchronous IO.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As VSG24 has said, you should await each and every call that can be *awaited* that is because this will help you keep the main thread free from any long running task — that are for instance, tasks that download data from internet, tasks that save the data to the disk using I/O etc. The problem was that whenever you had to do a long running task, it always froze the UI. To overcome this, asynchronous pattern was used and thus this async/await allows you create a function that does the long running task on the background and your main thread keeps *talking to the users*.

> I still not sure where do I use await operator in my async method

The intuition is that every function ending with `Async` can be awaited (provided their signature also matches, the following) and that they return either a `Task`, or `Task<T>`. Then they can be awaited using a function that returns void — you cannot await `void`. So the functions where there will be a bit longer to respond, you should apply await there. My own opinion is that a function that *might* take more than 1 second should be awaited — because that is a 1 second on your device, maybe your client has to wait for 5 seconds, or worse 10 seconds. They are just going to close the application and walk away saying, **It doesn't work!**.

> Ok, if one of these is very very fast, it does not need to be async, right ?

Fast in what manner? Don't forget that your clients may not have *very very fast* machines and they are definitely going to suffer from the frozen applications. So them a favor and always await the functions.

> What´s is the difference?

The difference is that in the last code sample, only the first call will be awaited and the others will execute synchronously. Visual Studio will also explain this part to you by providing green squiggly lines under the code that you can see by hovering over it. That is why, you should await every async call where possible.

**Tip**: If the process in the function is required, such as loading all of the data before starting the application then you should avoid async/await pattern and instead use the synchronous approach to download the data and perform other tasks. So it entirely depends on what you are doing instead of what the document says. :-)

Comment: In this case, this very fast is about 1ms.

Comment: The client's machine's speed doesn't really matter. This is ASP.NET, not WPF/WinForms.

Comment: @mason, then the cast is even **worst**. Each user would add up to 1MS of this function call to the request processing time. Add that to 100, 1000, or even 10,000 users if they have. How much will that add all upto? :-)

Comment: @Beetlejuice, see my above comment. In ASP.NET the case is even worse, because now we are talking about 100 users and every single user adding 1 ms to this function processing (not talking about entire request processing). And so on. So, you see how this helps. Read this from Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheMagicOfUsingAsynchronousMethodsInASPNET45PlusAnImportantGotcha.aspx, it will give you a quick understanding of using this pattern in ASP.NET. :-) I hope that helps you out too.

Comment: Your post misses the difference between ASP.NET development and desktop development. Making something async that is not I/O or network bound is likely just going to add unneeded overhead.

Comment: Async itself does not add anything to the system. Applying await is what makes it move the control over to the background thread. ASP.NET requires this even more, because your server is going to be busy doing things that will cause users to wait for the response. Kindly see the link I shared in the comment above.

Comment: Async does add overhead, and using it indiscriminately without understanding the consequences will lead to a slower application and more difficult to diagnose issues. Hanselman doesn't directly mention the overhead in his blog post, but he clearly chose Network I/O bound code, which is a good candidate for async. Not every method call however is a good candidate, such as CPU bound work in ASP.NET.

Comment: Then, you must have missed the Tip part, I said the same in that paragraph. :-) Anyways, let's close the discussion as SO wants us to start a debate somewhere.

Comment: `So the functions where the CPU is going to take a bit longer to respond, you should apply await there.` - this is exactly the opposite of what you want to do in ASP.NET.

Comment: You haven't fixed it. `My own opinion is that a function that might take more than 1 second should be awaited` - Making something CPU bound async is just going to make everything worse due to added overhead for the state machine and receiving no benefit.

Comment: Though the guideline "await everything call to something that is asynchronous" is not *terrible*, it is not *optimal* either, because it introduces unwanted control dependencies in the workflow. How can we come up with a better guideline? By recognizing that what we are awaiting is *the completion of the task*, and not *the call that generates the task*.  Once you make that distinction then it becomes easier to understand what needs to be awaited and when.  You need to await a task *before you need its result or effect*. Consider moving awaits to *later* than the call.

Comment: @mason: Making something CPU bound async can make things better if (1) there are many idle CPUs, and (2) the tasks are embarrassingly parallel.  If there aren't enough compute resources to service the task then obviously things are slow no matter how you divide up the tasks, and if the tasks are hard to parallelize then, by definition, they are hard to parallelize.

Answer (score 3):

> I still not sure where do I use await operator in my async method

You're approaching the problem from the wrong end.

The first thing to change when converting to `async` is the *lowest-level API calls*. There are some operations that are naturally asynchronous - specifically, I/O operations. Other operations are naturally synchronous - e.g., CPU code.

Based on the names "Find", "SearchForAppointments, and "SomeCalculation", I'd suspect that `Find` and `SearchForAppointments` are I/O-based, possibly hitting a database, while `SomeCalculation` is just doing some CPU calculation.

But don't change `Find` to `FindAsync` just yet. That's still going the wrong way. The right way is to start at the *lowest* API, so whatever I/O that `Find` eventually does. For example, if this is an EF query, then use the EF6 asynchronous methods *within* `Find`. Then `Find` should become `FindAsync`, which should drive `DailySchedule` to be `DailyScheduleAsync`, which causes its callers to become async, etc. That's the way that `async` should grow.

Answer (score 0):

Every `async` method call needs to be `await`ed, so that every method call releases the thread and thus not causing a block. Therefore in your case this is how you should do it:

```
var professional = await professionalServices.FindAsync(professionalId);            
var appointments = await scheduleService.SearchForAppointmentsasync(date, professional);
appointments = await scheduleService.SomeCalculationAsync(appointments);
```

Comment: Ok, if one of these is very very fast, it does not need to be async, right ?

Comment: If you are **absolutely**  sure that it's very fast (and is NOT I/O), then it's best to do it synchronously, less memory usage.